# Using Azure AI Immersive Reader in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-cognitive-services, immersive-reader

I am trying to use Azure IA Immersive reader in ReactJS app.
I have created a resource on Azure Portal
I have the Key and Endpoint of Immersive reader resource.
[image]

Trying to use '@microsoft/immersive-reader-sdk' via code below:

```
 function launchImmersiveReader() {
    const content = {
      title: 'Immersive Reader',
      chunks: [ {
          content: 'Hello, world!'
      } ]
  };
    
    launchAsync({
      key: ----------,
      endPoint: 'https://abc-dfg-dev.cognitiveservices.azure.com/',
      content: content,
  });
}
```

Calling this function on button click

```
<button onClick={launchImmersiveReader}>Launch Immersive Reader</button>
```

But it gives me error message code: `BadArgument`, message:`Content must not be null`

Comment: @Sampath, actually this is the complete code just want to initialize the immersive reader .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/immersive-reader-sdk/blob/b5b2b4fb40b05babd7ebb7d7064e00e8c65d2ba0/js/samples/react-sample-simple/src/App.js#L87C1-L88C1).
You have to pass the token, subdomain, content and options.

```
try {
  await launchAsync(token, process.env.REACT_APP_SUBDOMAIN, data, options)
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  alert("Error in launching the Immersive Reader. Check the console.");
}
```